# First day and last day of times series depending on a dummy variable SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, time-series, dummy-variable

I would like to get the first day and last day of times series depending on a dummy variable SQL.
I have an item and for each day I hve a dummy variable which indicates if the item was online or not.
For example, see the following data for just the some specific days:

```
Item    Day         Online
car     01/02/2020  1
car     02/02/2020  1
car     03/02/2020  0
car     04/02/2020  1
car     05/02/2020  1
van     01/02/2020  0
van     02/02/2020  1
van     03/02/2020  0
van     04/02/2020  1
van     05/02/2020  0
bike    01/02/2020  0
bike    02/02/2020  0
bike    03/02/2020  0
bike    04/02/2020  0
bike    05/02/2020  0
```

I would need a result similar to the following one:

```
car:
first day : 01/02/2020
last day : 02/02/2020
first day and last day : 03/02/2020
first day : 04/02/2020
last day : 05/02/2020

van:
first day and last day : 01/02/2020
first day and last day : 02/02/2020
first day and last day : 03/02/2020
first day and last day : 04/02/2020
first day and last day : 05/02/2020

bike:
first day : 01/02/2020
first day and last day : 05/02/2020
```

I'm totally lost and I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me about it.
Thank you!

Comment: Please explain what `online` has to do with the results.  I'm sure it is involved somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to divide the periods of online and offline for each item.  This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  A general method is:

```
select item, online, min(day), max(day)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by day) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by item, online order by day) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by item, online, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

The point of using the row numbers is to define groups where the `online` flag is the same.  The difference of the row numbers is constant on adjacent rows where the values are the same.

In your particular case, the `online` has just two statuses.  You could instead use a cumulative sum of the status like this:

```
select item, online, min(day), max(day)
from (select t.*,
             sum(online) over (partition by item order by day) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by item, online, grp;
```